# Salesforce Community and Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, community, slds

it's possible to use Lightning Experience in Community?

Now I have a Community with Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce template and I used classic style to develope pages.
I would develop new Visusalforce Pages with SLDS (Salesforce Lightning Design System) to have Lightning style but I don't want use Lightning Component.

Is possible to realize my request, so have visualforce page with SLDS and Lightning Experience (headerbar, sidebar) but without Lightning Component?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.

Download Lightning Desing System from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ and add it as a static resource.

In the VisualForce Page add a reference to the stylesheet

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.GP_SLDS, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}" />
```

The must follow the guidelines from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/

Comment: With Lightning Experience I intend sidebar and headerbar as for salesforce user.

Comment: I think Salesoforce is going to add LE to Community. But, now, you must draw yourseff the headerbar, sidebar, following the guidelines in https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components-overview/